# Mage registry key Already Exist Magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, key

I have used the Observer event in my Custom module, but when i load the added event, it is showing below error message,

Mage Registry key "Observer" already exists.

I have checked the Compiler Mode, it is in Disable state.

I am using  event, Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_status_history_save_before>
            <observers>
                <auto_order_statua>
                    <class>Custom_Status_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                </auto_order_statua>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_status_history_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer.php

```
class Custom_Status_Model_Observer
{

    public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //$order = $observer->getOrder();
        //$stateProcessing = $order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        //$state = $order->getState();
        mail('nagamaniatnaresh@gmail.com', 'test', 'test');
    }

}
```

Comment: And what code you are using inside your observer ? Is there any call to `Mage::register` in there ?

Comment: I am just using mail function to check whether it was triggered.

Comment: Well then, your module doesn't seem to be the culprit. Try removing this event and see if error still persists.

Comment: When i removed the Event from XML it is working fine, but when i add the codes for Event, it gets started...

Answer (score 0):

In `config.xml` you should change name your event as(some_unique_identifier must unique)

```
    <events>
        <name_of_event_in_magento>
            <observers>
                <some_unique_identifier>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Vendor_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>yourMethod</method>
                </some_unique_identifier>
            </observers>
        </name_of_event_in_magento>
    </events>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Paw, I have updated the code in the Question

Comment: @Nagamani, it woking ??

Comment: No its not @Paw

Comment: Are you add "<type>singleton</type>" in <auto_order_statua> ?

Comment: Yes i tried with that Too...

Comment: Now, Are you receive error after event?

Comment: yes i receive after clicking submit button @paw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31901/discussion-between-nagamani-and-paw).

Answer (score 0):

In *`Config.xml`*

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Status>
        <version>0.0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Status>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <status>
            <class>Custom_Status</class>
        </status>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_status_history_save_before>
            <observers>
                <custom_status>
                    <class>Custom_Status_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                </custom_status>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_status_history_save_before>
    </events>
<global>
```

Comment: Added Abdul <class>Custom_Status_Model</class> but no improvement

Comment: what issue is coming?

Comment: I am facing this error **Mage registry key "_singleton/Custom_Status_Model_Observer" already exists**

Comment: can you please change name Custom_Status_Model_Observer to Custom_Test_Model_Observer

Comment: then working or not?

Comment: I have tried as per your Suggestion, but still same error, Please refer link for Screenshot http://prntscr.com/9577qz

Comment: okay let me try my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31902/discussion-between-nagamani-and-abdul).